# How to delete a view named ".."

Tags: jenkins, hudson, cloudbees

I created a new view in Cloudbees and, while configuring it, wanted it to remain somewhat unnoticed by the rest of my team. I renamed the view to "..", just because it was the first thing that came to mind.

Now I can't delete the group, because the use of ".." is interpreted as directory traversal.

- I cannot navigate to the view by clicking the tab, since "https://{account}.ci.cloudbees.com/view/../" is the "https://{account}.ci.cloudbees.com/".

  - I *can* navigate to this view, but only by setting this as the default view inside "Manage Jenkins".
- By the same URL pattern issues, I also cannot write a URL appropriate for deleting this view.

Comment: In general, don't name things `.` or `..`, as I'm sure you have just learned.

Comment: That's a smart thing to remember. I sometimes forget that software is only as smart as its developers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just as I was finishing this question, I had another idea which was successful. I found by accident that "https://{account}.ci.cloudbees.com/view/../delete" will delete the default view. Another test confirmed that "https://{account}.ci.cloudbees.com/delete" deletes the default view.

1. In "Manage Jenkins", set ".." as the default view.
2. Enter "https://{account}.ci.cloudbees.com/delete" into the URL bar.
3. Go back to "Manage Jenkins" to set a new default view.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Jenkins that it let you create a view with this name to begin with. File in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS if you have a moment.

Comment: an update: [JENKINS-16608](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16608) has been marked as fixed.

Comment: This just saved me.  I was making a new view, and on the second page of creating it, I clicked on the main jenkins link.  This committed an unconfigured view, crashing jenkins.  I hand-typed http://jenkins/views/my dumb view name/delete and it purged the faulty view, and thus also the crashing java code for the main index.

Answer (score 33):

Please specify Jenkins server, port and view name to delete custom view:

```
http://<jenkins-server>:<port>/view/<view name>/delete
```

Jenkins is problematic in this particular functionality.